# produce can only be called on things that are draftable: plain objects, arrays, Map, Set or classes that are marked with '[immerable]: true'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, firebase-authentication

I got following error at onAuthStateChanged method at `store.dispatch(userActions.setUser(null));`

> Error: [Immer] produce can only be called on things that are draftable: plain objects, arrays, Map, Set or classes that are marked with '[immerable]: true'. Got '[object Object]'

I am trying to change to firebase authentication from jwt. So custom jwt authentication is using redux. Now when I call firebase's signOut(auth) method, onAuthStateChanged method give me this error. May I know how to write immerable object for user.

user_reducer.js

```
import produce from "immer";
import * as Action_Constants from "../actions/user_actions";

const initialState = null;

export const UserReducer = produce((state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Action_Constants.SET_USER: {
      return action.user;
    }
    case Action_Constants.FETCH_USER_COMPLETED: {
      return action.user;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
});
```

user_actions.js

```
export const FETCH_USER = "FETCH_USER";
export const FETCH_USER_COMPLETED = "FETCH_USER_COMPLETED";

export const SET_USER = "SET_USER";

export const actionCreators = {
  fetchUser: (id) => ({
    type: FETCH_USER,
    id,
  }),

  fetchUserCompleted: (user) => ({
    type: FETCH_USER_COMPLETED,
    user,
  }),

  setUser: (user) => ({
    type: SET_USER,
    user,
  }),
};
```

I have deleted other firebase functions to simply the file.

auth_provider.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, createContext } from "react";
import { useLocation, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { signIn, signUp } from "../helpers/gql_auth_helpers";
import paths from "../routes/paths";
import { store } from "../store/configure_store";
import { actionCreators as userActions } from "../store/actions/user_actions";
import { auth } from "../helpers/init-firebase";
import {
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signOut,
} from "firebase/auth";

const AuthContext = createContext(null);
let accessToken = "";

export const getAccessToken = () => accessToken;
export const setAccessToken = (token) => {
  accessToken = token;
};

export const AuthProvider = ({ user: usr, children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(usr);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
        setAccessToken(user.getIdToken(true));
        store.dispatch(userActions.setUser(user));
      } else {
        setUser(null);
        setAccessToken(null);
        store.dispatch(userActions.setUser(null));
      }
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  async function logout() {
    return signOut(auth);
  }

  const value = {
    user,
    accessToken,
    logout,
  };

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};
```